# Facebook Login Api Error even domain has lets encrypt SSL - Insecure Login

Tags: facebook-login

> Insecure Login Blocked: You can't get an access token or log in to this app from an insecure page. Try re-loading the page as https://

Error message says there is no SSL at your domain which you tried to use the API, but I already added it to Valid OAuth Redirect URIs so this makes no sense.

Cause validator says this is a valid redirect URI for this application  and I am using a wordpress plugin named `Woocommerce` Social Login. Its settings also offering the valid URI.

What can be the cause now? They(FB) don't accept the **Lets Encrypt SSL as an SSL** anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the situation by just checkin the url requested when we try to login with facebook, it shows http instead of https. So the source of the problem is wordpress social login plugin.

`https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth?client_id=<ClientID>&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2example.com%2F%3Fwc-api%3Dauth%26done%3Dfacebook&response_type=code&scope=public_profile%2C%20email`

Comment: I have same issue. But I can't figure out where I can to change callback URL. Where did you find it?

Comment: A little late response but maybe usefull for others so if u want to change your Callback URL you must first go to facebook developers and go to your facebook login settings. There are all the settings like valid oauth uri etc. Also you can use `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOUR-APP-ID/fb-login/settings/` dont forget to change `YOUR-APP-ID`. @Angelzzz